# How to create Up & Down Arrow in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

In iOS 7 when we navigate the mails in any mailbox, there are up/down arrows at top-right corner. I am looking for those exact same images for my up/down buttons. My question is : Are there any system resources like UIBarButtonSystemItem that we can use as is OR this is something we need to create the custom images ourself?

Attached is the image for reference:

[image]

Comment: I did not understand, why -1 for this question?

Comment: This is a legitim question! Strange that they are not a standard icon.

Answer (score 4):

There is an iOS artwork extractor project on github here https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor. Download it, and run it in your iOS7 simulator. This will extract a *lot* of stuff!

In the search bar, search for `UIButtonBarArrow`, and you will see examples of the arrows that you mention. You can them save the required ones to disk.

NOTE: I don't know the legal/copyright position regarding using these images directly in your own project, however, Apple haven't asked the creator of this tool to take it down, so read into that what you will. Personally, I would recommend loading them into something like Photoshop to use as a guide to create your own artwork, then there will be no issues.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning name of the resource!

Answer (score 4):

Check this GitHub repo for iOS 7 UIKit resources: https://github.com/youknowone/UIKitResources